# CPU temperature reaches 100 degree on stress when plugged in

Tags: laptop, cpu, battery, cooling, temperature

My laptop runs fine when using battery and plugged in while normal use. But whenever I try to load some heavy software like android studio or install a game or run a game. The temperature shoots up to 100 degree.
When i unplug the charger it goes back to normal like 70 degree and goes up only when it is plugged in. The adapter is original one and tried using another one too but got no change.
One thing more the fan runs alot faster that time and when i touch my laptop it isn't as hot as it should be for 100 degrees but pretty normal.
Should I be worried or just get on with it.

Comment: Have you cleaned the fan and heatsink radiator lately? Is the fan running on high at 100?

Comment: @Moab The fan and heatsink are already cleaned. Fan runs too fast on 100 degrees if that what you asking

Comment: make sure the laptop is on a hard surface (table, desk, etc) and not on a bed, couch. If the battery is removable, try removing it and leaving it plugged in while high usage. Battery charging might increase heat. If this continue, invest in a chill mat.

Comment: If you are running Windows check the energy performance settings for the plugged-in state. "Balanced" energy saver plan should be selected.

Comment: “Fan runs too fast on 100 degrees if that what you asking” - Why do you say that?  At 100 Degrees I would expect the heatsink fan to run at 100% until temperatures were back to normal.  At 100 degrees that’s an indication your processor is being thermally throttled and is nearing its maximum thermal temperatures before outright shutting down to protect itself from damage

Comment: @GeekyDaddy Laptop is not on bed or couch. And the battery is non replaceable.

Comment: @Robert Power plan is balanced by default.

Comment: @Ramhound The temperature don't drop even if the fan is running on high speed. As soon as I unplug the charger the fan starts running normal and temperature drops.